# Can't deploy a config rule through the CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, config, aws-cdk

I'm working on applying config rules in my organisation by leveraging Python CDK for AWS. In my setup I have a list of managed config rules from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-rules/blob/master/aws-config-conformance-packs/Operational-Best-Practices-for-CIS-AWS-v1.4-Level2.yaml#L450). This list is in the stack that would be further deployed through a stackset. I've got a problem with some config rules from the conformance pack. For some reason cloudformation is not accepting `SourceIdentifier: AWS_CONFIG_PROCESS_CHECK`

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    core as cdk,
    aws_config as config,
)
....
class TestConfigRulesStack(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        self.rule = config.ManagedRule(
          self,
          'ManagedRule-test',
          config_rule_name='account-contact-details-configured',
          identifier='AWS_CONFIG_PROCESS_CHECK',
        )
....
```

The error:

```
The sourceIdentifier AWS_CONFIG_PROCESS_CHECK is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for a list of valid sourceIdentifiers that can be used when AWS is the Owner. (Service: AmazonConfig; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: <request_id>; Proxy: null)
```

CDK output:

```json
...
        "JSIIMetaManagedRuleaccountcontactdetailsconfigured9BA14D66": {
            "Type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule",
            "Properties": {
                "Source": {
                    "Owner": "AWS",
                    "SourceIdentifier": "AWS_CONFIG_PROCESS_CHECK"
                },
                "ConfigRuleName": "account-contact-details-configured",
                "Description": "Ensure the contact email and telephone number for AWS accounts are current and map to more than one individual in your organization. Within the My Account section of the console ensure correct information is specified in the Contact Information section."
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "aws:cdk:path": "<path>"
            }
        },
    ...
```

here is the the config rule from the official template:

```yaml
  AccountContactDetailsConfigured:
    Properties:
      ConfigRuleName: account-contact-details-configured
      Description: Ensure the contact email and telephone number for AWS accounts are current and map to more than one individual in your organization. Within the My Account section of the console ensure correct information is specified in the Contact Information section.
      Source:
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: AWS_CONFIG_PROCESS_CHECK
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
```

am I missing something? I don't get why it doesn't work.

Comment: AWS_CONFIG_PROCESS_CHECK should be deployed only through the conformance pack object (CfnConformancePack). So I took the class with the list of rules and converted it into a YAML file for TemplateBody.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are creating a new rule with an identifier that is the same as an existing AWS-owned ManagedRule.

To import an existing rule instead of creating a new one, use [`ManagedRule.fromConfigRuleName`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-config.ManagedRule.html#static-fromwbrconfigwbrrulewbrnamescope-id-configrulename):

```py
rule = config.ManagedRule.from_config_rule_name(
    self,
    'ManagedRule-test',
    config_rule_name='account-contact-details-configured'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a default AWS managed rule, you only need to use the constant for it located in `aws_cdk.aws_config.ManagedRuleIdentifiers` wherever you would attach that rule. You don't need to import the rule with from_config or any other from functionality.

Just wherever your construct you are using the rule as part of takes an iRule, you can use `aws_cdk.aws_config.ManagedRuleIdentifiers.THE_NAME_OF_THE_RULE`

or, based off your imports

`config.ManagedRuleIdentifiers.THE_NAME_OF_THE_RULE`

you can get a list of AWS managed rules and their constant value here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_config/ManagedRuleIdentifiers.html

If it is not an AWS managed rule, and you have already created it through another method (another stack, manually, another cloudformation template) then you do need to import it into this stack with the from_ functionalities.

If it is created in another CDK stack you can expose it from that stack and use it as a parameter in any other stacks you will need it in, but i reccomend you make them all nestedStacks and put them under a common app so you don't have deployment dependency issues